# ExpressJS - Sequelize - Column Missing Error

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to properly query all images that fit my sequelize query in addition to the description that is connected to the specific query, but I receive an error for a `createdAt` column, which is not located in my table. How can I specify the columns I want to use within my query?

Here is the query (The pattern and color are correctly pulled into the query):

```
router.get('/:pattern/:color/result', function(req, res){

    console.log(req.params.color);
    console.log(req.params.pattern);

    Images.findAll({ 
        where: {
            pattern: req.params.pattern,
            color: req.params.color
        }
        });
        //console.log(image);
        //console.log(doc.descriptions_id);
        res.render('pages/result.hbs', {
            pattern : req.params.pattern,
            color : req.params.color,
            image : image
        });

});
```

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pattern` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  `color` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imageUrl` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imageSource` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `description_id` (`description_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `images_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`description_id`) REFERENCES `description` (`description_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=47 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here is the error:

```
   Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `pattern`, `color`, `imageUrl`, `imageSource`, `description_id`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `images` AS `images` WHERE `images`.`pattern` = 'solid' AND `images`.`color` = 'navy-blue';
    Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'createdAt' in 'field list'
        at Query.formatError (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/assistant/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:160:14)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can explicitly set which attributes (column names) you want to retrieve in your query.  For example, if you wanted to retrieve the `id`, `pattern`, `color`, `imageUrl`, and `imageSource` columns you can use the following code:

```
Images.findAll({
    where : {
        pattern: req.params.pattern,
        color: req.params.color
    },
    attributes : ['id', 'pattern', 'color', 'imageUrl', 'imageSource']
})
```

Answer (score 9):

By default, sequelize assumes that you have timestamps in your table. This can be disabled either globally

```
new Sequelize(..., { define: { timestamps: false }});
```

Or per model:

```
sequelize.define(name, attributes, { timestamps: false });
```

Or if you only have some timesstamps (fx updated, but not created)

```
sequelize.define(name, attributes, { createdAt: false });
```

In case your column is called something else:

```
sequelize.define(name, attributes, { createdAt: 'make_at' });
```

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/

In this way, you don't have to specify all attributes each time - sequelize knows which attributes it can actually select.

If you really wanted to specify which attributes should be selected by 
default you could use a scope

```
sequelize.define(name, attributes, { defaultScope { attributes: [...] }});
```

And that will be applied to each find call